# Let cmake with clang use c++11 (c++14)

Tags: c++11, stl, cmake, clang, c++14

My cmake project shall compile c++14 code. It also uses the CMakeLists.txts included from its external libraries (which are git submodules in my project). The build fails on macOS Sierra (cmake 3.6.2) because [the default STL of clang is old and doesn't handle c++11](https://cplusplusmusings.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/clang-and-standard-libraries-on-mac-os-x/). As far as I understand, there are two STLs shipped with clang: *libstdc++* (from gcc) (default) or *libc++*. So if I add the `-stdlib=libc++` option to cmake, the source compiles:

```
add_compile_options( "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-std=c++14>" )
add_compile_options( "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-stdlib=libc++>" )
```

But then it fails at link time because it tries to use *libstdc++* for linking. How do I specify in cmake that the new STL *libc++* shall be used for the whole build process?

**PS:** What is the rationale behind clang using the gcc STL by default if it is too old? Could I permanently specify which STL it shall use? Or am I doing something completely wrong (could some of my subprojects silently force gcc?)?

Comment: Update: My problem with wrong stdlib (and questions above) was caused by a line `set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7)` in one of my sub-CMakeLists.txt; see comment below!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should rely on CMake to handle compile options. Just specify the wanted standard version:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

`target_compile_features` can also be used to require particular features of the standard (and implicitly ask CMake to set the adequate configuration). More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220265/check-if-a-c11-feature-is-enabled-in-compiler-with-cmake/41221098#41221098).

---

**EDIT**

You figured out the solution, you also had to remove the following line in the CMakeLists of Ogred3D:

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7)
```

Removing it prevented CMake to add the flag `mmacosx-version-min=10.7` causing the error.

Comment: It does not work for me. I have Ogre3D as a submodule. Let us only consider to build it standalone. cmake configuring goes well, but compilation (via make) fails. Consider its CMakeLists.txt: https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/108ab0bcc69603dba32c0ffd4bbbc39051f421c9/CMakeLists.txt?at=v1-9. If I remove lines 35-43 and add your code at top, the compilation fails (unknown STL templates from c++14). Keeping the CMakeLists.txt as is, compilation goes well (c++11).

Comment: After lot a of digging (by looking at compiler calls with `make VERBOSE=1` for cmake), it was a flag `mmacosx-version-min=10.7` to clang causing the compile error [by giving it the wrong headers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2927217/753850). It turned out that the _CMakeLists.txt_ by Ogre3D was the problem: It had a line `set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7)`.

This actually solves my question totally!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, you also need to pass that flang to the linker in the clang case:

```
link_libraries("-stdlib=libc++")
```

Comment: Thank you! I will first try to get `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` work (as in the above answer), but your answer is what I was searching for in the first place (have not tried it yet, though).